# Implementation of RESTful Services using Design patterns

Tags: asp.net

Can you provide me some URL's where i can find design pattern code examples for implementing restful services.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried googling it? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd943053.aspx or is there something specific that you are looking for that you haven't found?  please provide more details.

Answer (score 1):

There can be different ways implementation [RESTful services](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-restful/) in the ASP.NET. For example,

1. Using WCF ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd315413.aspx )
2. Using ASP.NET MVC ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd943053.aspx )
3. Using ASP.NET WebForms or HttpHandlers (see http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/RestServicesInASPNET2.aspx or [Possible to create REST web service with ASP.NET 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40692/possible-to-create-rest-web-service-with-asp-net-2-0))

Once you understand principals of RESTful services, you can use any web development framework to create them. From framework perspective, I will rather prefer WCF.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.I am particularly looking for best design patterns code examples that talk to Database(for eg; get users) from service. Assume i have created restful service using WCF now what are the best design patterns to fetch records from DB.

Comment: @Amarnath, in general, principal remains same! For example, you should be using layered design that separate concerns such as db persistence. The services layer would be the outer-most layer (e.g. services layer -> business facase -> business layer -> data access -> data store)

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial provides a good start to using the [WCF WEB API](http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20HTTP) - what the author calls the '[new face of REST](http://tugberkugurlu.com/archive/introduction-to-wcf-web-api-new-rest-face-ofnet)'

Learning how to use the Wcf Web Api will cover a lot of REST concepts / designs